# iTerm2: how to enable auto-scroll down after I manually scroll up?

Tags: scroll, jestjs, tdd, iterm2, iterm

How can I set up iTerm2 so that it auto-scrolls down even after I scroll up manually?

See GIF below. It starts scrolling down normally, but stops after I manually scroll up, even that output is still coming to stdout.

Changing this would help me a lot running jest tests in watch mode.

[image: sample situation: terminal scrolls down automatically only before I manually scroll up]